# What is the equations tensorflow/deeplearning4j using for LSTM network?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, deeplearning4j

This is a simple question. Deeplearning4J and Tensorflow uses the same equations to compute and train a neural network.

When I create a feed forward neural network, e.g `DenseLayer`, and then I extract the weight matrices and vectors, I get the following:

```
0_W, 0_b
```

Where the zero (0) tells me that it's the first layer and `W` is the weight matrix and `b` is the bias vector. The equation for that layer are:

```
output = 0_W * input + 0_b
```

Easy! But when I create a `LSTM` layer, and then I extract the following matrices and vector:

```
0_W, 0_WR, 0_b
```

So what is the equation for that layer? Is it:

```
output = 0_W * input + 0_WR * past_input + 0_b
```

? According to the equations for LSTM, it looks more like this:

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/17412/64391) a (partial) answer to your question?

Comment: @dedObed Not really. I think that DL4J/Tensor uses different equations for solve the same problem.

Comment: They don't include computation of the memory and the output, but they show how you get a single matrix of parameters (and use them), covering equations 1--4 of Colah's description.

Comment: @dedObed So if I got 0_W, 0_WR, 0_b...what can I do with them after I have get them from the DL-model?

Comment: @dedObed Or could it be that if I extract the weights from an LSTM layer, I get the weights for a simple RNN layer?